# How to run two images on same machine in docker swarm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I use docker swarm with several machines and several images. In particulat, I have database and container, that shedules backups. I need to start them on same machine. How i can setup this with docker-compose?

```
version: "3"
services:
    my_mongodb:
        image: mongo
        environment:
          - MONGO_DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR}
        networks:
         - webnet
    my_backup:
        image: mybackup
        environment:
          - MONGO_DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR}
   #other images
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an affinity filter to the my_backup environment:

```
my_backup:
    image: my backup
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR}
      - "affinity:image==mongo"
```

Unfortunately there is no "affinity:service" which will make it very easy to do this kind of things. You can learn more about filters in the [docker docs for swarm scheduler filters](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/swarm/scheduler/filter.md).

There is also an interesting discussion about supporting an `affinity:service` filter in the [this issue in the docker/swarmkit](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1442) GitHub repo.